# How to Bypass HTTPContext Usage .?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tdd, mocking, moq

```
var mockedService = new Mock<IService>();
mockedService.Setup(x => x.InterfaceMethod(args)).Returns(value);
_Service = mockedService.Object;
MyController controller =new MyController(_Service);

var result = (ViewResult)controller.Foo();
```

Now this Foo() Method contains  the Following API Call

```
HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(...,..);
```

But the HTTPContext is null, as i'm just unit testing , i have not Authenticated. and hence not populated the HTTPContext Object.

I cant set expectations on this class because the **HTTPContext** is sealed.

I've been searching in the net , but there were only samples to fake the **HTTPContextBase**

Now how do i get my Unit Test to Pass. Any Suggestions.?

thanks ,

vijay

Comment: There is definitely something wrong with the second code chunk...

Comment: I mean, first you make a new controller instance and the next line throws it away by re-assigning the controller variable.

Comment: In the second code snippet, why are you assigning to the controller variable twice? The first line seems redundant.

Comment: And by the way, what is the question?

Comment: @vijaysylvester: Please edit your question. Right now it is not clear what it is that you are trying to do, which is why you are getting no answers. I'd like to help, but don't understand what you are attempting.

Comment: I have edited my answer based on your changes to your question in the "Edit" section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not setting up an expectation for the "Centres" method.  When you mock an object all implementations are replaced with a Noop until you specify otherwise using an Expectation.

I'm guessing you mocked `GetValueFromResource` rather than `Centres` because `Centres` *calls* `GetValueFromResource`.  If this is the case, mocking `GetValueFromResource` is likely a superfluous fake and you don't need it.

Also, as has been pointed out on several other Moq posts, you'll need to make sure that you are not mocking what you are testing.  If you are actually trying to test MyController, you'd want to mock any dependencies it has, but not MyController itself.  This will cause you no end of confusion.

**Edit**

Based on this feedback it seems you have learned that your true problem is that you need to mock HTTPContext.  Mocking HTTPContext is nontrivial.  There are a few tools that can do it natively, like Type Mock, but the problem is that ambient context is not testable.

What you *should* be doing is requesting dependencies that give you the information you need while abstracting away their implementation.  For example, in your case it seems like you are using HTTPContext to access resources.  If you need something like this a good interface you could use would be:

```
public interface IResourceStore
{
     object GetGlobalResource(string  classKey, string resourceKey);
}
```

Your default implementation would use HTTPContext, but now you have an interface you can mock and have your MyController class use, rather than HTTPContext directly.

```
Mock<IResourceStore> resourceStore = new Mock<IResourceStore>();
//setup resourceStore expectations here

MyController testingTarget = new MyController(_Service, resourceStore.Object);
//target assertions here
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Anderson GetValueFromResource() method is using HTTPContext , so when that API call is encountered , the null reference exception is thrown . now what do i do. ? Any suggestions.?

Comment: I usually create a helper class that accesses HTTPContext for me that I use from my class that needs HTTPContext.  This way you avoid referencing HTTPContext from everywhere.  Alternatively there are quite a few tutorials on mocking HTTPContext on the internet.  Regardless I hope you have learned that mocking what you are testing is not a good idea.

Comment: Can we Manually setup the HTTPCOntext Object . 

like this HTTPcontext context =new HTTPCOntext(Req,Res).
After Manually constructing the Req and Res Objects.?

Comment: there's no reason to.  The ResourceStore is meant to use HTTPContext, but if you mock it (like you should), it won't need to access HTTPContext... it'll be fake.